# Sharepoint alternate ideas to get report from multiple user

Tags: sharepoint, report

We've a real pain in our project where we ask a team of 50 resources to update a single excel sheet that's placed in a network location and when someone tries to update the data, it's locked by somebody else and they don't update it. So, they end up not updating the data.

I'm looking for an alternate solution like

- creating a form in sharepoint/ jira - no sharepoint/ jira developer
- getting data in mail - too tedious and lots of rework
- creating a custom form and hosting it in local server - might work - any templates on this?

Or, any alternates? I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easiest thing would be to create a simple [SharePoint-List](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-list-in-sharepoint-0d397414-d95f-41eb-addd-5e6eff41b083). All Users can update their data at the same time and the Input-Form will be there automatically. (Can also be exported to Excel)

If you are on SharePoint-Online you could also have a look at [Windows Form](https://forms.office.com/) which provide more flexibility in creating the form.

And if you need even more capabilities you can have a look at [PowerApps](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/de-de/)

Comment: Any alternate to using SharePoint?

Comment: I also agree with benniz that SharePoint list is a easiest option. You will not need developer to create sharepoint list. Forms get generated automatically.